# Small list of project templates

Tags: keil

Trying to create firs project in Keil uVision. I need to create application for ARM Cortex M3 LPC1768. When I do Project->New uVision project and save it I got list of processors:

[image]

According to tutorial I [found](http://www.circuitstoday.com/getting-started-with-keil-uvision) list should be much bigger:
[image]

How I can get such list of templates and how to create project for ARM Cortex M3 LPC1768?

UPD.

I have downloaded my processors pack from http://www.keil.com/dd2/nxp/lpc1768
It opens by PackUnzip.exe utility for Keil v 5 as default. But I can't find same utility for Keil V4. Where it is?

I can't find

```
"Pack installer" on toolbar , click on "Check For Updates" in "Packs" Menu
```

There is nothing simmilar in my Keil v4 and Keil V5. Where they are? This is how looks my main window.

Keil V4:
[image]

Keil V5:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Keil version is 5 and in the tutorial is 4. you should install Keil 4 or go to keil 5 and open "Pack installer" on toolbar , click on "Check For Updates" in "Packs" Menu. All of the available processors will install.
also you can go http://www.keil.com/dd2/nxp/lpc1768 and download LPC1768 Pack and import it from Pack Installer (File -> Import) and create new project.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem , but I need more details described in question body UPD section